# inferior limit of a sequence intuition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, intuition

With an integral you have the idea of the area below a curve, what is the idea with the notion of inferior limit and superior limit of a sequence?, Imean, what is the picture?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Think of inferior and superior as asking "what is the greatest/least value for all terms after term $n$"

The limit of these just let's $n\to \infty$. if $\lim \inf< \lim \sup$ then the sequence does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

The limit inferior of a sequence is the smallest limit point of a sequence. If you google *limit inferior*, you will immediately find the following picture (see [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limes_superior_und_Limes_inferior)).
[image: See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limes_superior_und_Limes_inferior]